# Why is Calendar in my Users-List null? - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, api

I need the Calendars of the Users, but they're null. The Graph API gives me the users and they're not null, because the users' names are printable.
My Code:

```
var token = _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read", "Calendars.Read", "Calendars.Read.Shared" }).Result;
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(request =>
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }));

            var usersList = graphClient.Users.Request()
                .Select(x => x.Calendar).GetAsync().Result;

            usersList.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (x.Calendar == null || x.Calendar.Name == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Calendar-Name: null");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Calendar-Name: {x.Calendar.Name}");
                }
            });
```

As you can see in the picture, my code always prints "Calendar-Name: null":
[console-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0u1H.png)
Does someone know an answer to get the calendars from the users?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your code logic seems correct, but I believe calling:

```
var usersList = graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select(x => x.Calendar).GetAsync().Result;
```

Is not enough. Since this is an asynchronous operation, you need to wait for it to end and return the result instead of fetching the result right away.

Please verify if you can place a `.Wait()` before `.Result` so this line looks like the following:

```
var usersList = graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select(x => x.Calendar).GetAsync().Wait().Result;
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it isn't possible to put a ```.Wait()``` before ```.Result```. The thing is that the request works, because if I wanna get the user names for example I write ```.Select(x => x.DisplayName)``` and that works, but with Calendar it doesn't work because Calendar is null.

Comment: @code_coding_coder thank you for the reply. What about this:
add this namespace `using System.Data.Entity` to your project, then change your query to this:
`var usersList = graphClient.Users.Request().Include("Calendar").Select(x => x.Calendar).GetAsync().Result;`

Comment: I used this [reference](https://www.educba.com/linq-include/), I've been using `Include()` a lot for querying. Without specifying this Includes, my queries would only select the object main Properties. Data constrained with foreign keys (associated with an Id, for instance) was not being processed, and maybe that is what's happening with your example. Maybe adding this `Include()` will fix your issue!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that also doesn't work, because ```.Include(x => x.Calendar)``` is only useable after an IQueryable and in my example there is no such IQueryable. But again thanks for the effort!